# Angular - sharing image between components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to show the 'app-title-icon' before the Title but the icon does not appear...

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndwttf

```
<h1>
  <app-title-icon></app-title-icon>Title
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correct image path

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sharing-image-between-components?file=src/app/title-icon/title-icon.component.css)**

```
.title-icon {
    content: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/673865/pexels-photo-673865.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260); 
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code, the image url has some problem maybe its not returning the required image because when i used some other image url it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in console, you're being warned with message `request-wrapper.js:229 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response`

try another URL or local URL or exact image URL not site URL